# how to check whether two matrices are identical in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have two instances of cv::Mat : m1 and m2. They are of the same numeric type and sizes.
Is there any function in OpenCV that returns whether the matrices are identical (have all the same values)?

Answer (score 66):

As mentioned by Acme, you can use [`cv::compare`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#compare) although it is not as clean as you might hope.
In the following example, `cv::compare` is called by using the [`!=` operator](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrixexpressions):

```
// Get a matrix with non-zero values at points where the 
// two matrices have different values
cv::Mat diff = a != b;
// diff is boolean matrix so all elements are non-negative. Equal if all elements in diff are zero.
bool eq2 = cv::sum(diff) == cv::Scalar(0,0,0,0);
```

If you know the type you can use the STL [equal](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/equal/) function. The Mat iterators take care of cases where the data is non-contiguous, and you can use a vector type for multichannel matrices.

```
bool eq = std::equal(a.begin<uchar>(), a.end<uchar>(), b.begin<uchar>());
```

*Edit: Improve my earlier update to handle multichannel case based on Miki's answer.*

Comment: `bool eq = cv::countNonZero(a!=b) == 0;`.  I think this is reasonably clean.  The most annoying thing is that you have to invert the comparison operator compared to what you actually want to know (`!=` instead of `==`) since there is no `countZero()` function.

Comment: The cv::Mat may or may not continuous, I am not sure the bytes padding by each row has the same value.

Comment: Yes but I believe the Mat iterators take care of this for you? http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-begin

Comment: Why do you say that `cv::compare` might not be clean?

Comment: Been a while, but I guess because the test reads as a double negative (equal if the are _no_ non-zeroes in a _not equals_ b), which I think is less clear than something like A == B.

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you meant! Please check if you agree with my edit. (Note: Please add an @Antonio if you want me to be notified about your comments)

Comment: For some reason "cv::Mat diff = a != b;" is changing the actual contents of a for me! Beware...

Comment: link is dead for `cv::compare`

Comment: @opa Link fixed.

Comment: This solution is NOT VALID FOR MULTI-CHANNEL as cv::countNonZero is only for single channel.

Comment: @Josep Bosch Thanks for flagging. I've updated the answer to include multichannel cases.

Comment: Hmm the multichannel version did not work for me. Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231565/countnonzero-function-gives-an-assertion-error-in-opencv?noredirect=1&lq=1 suggests `countNonZero()` works for one channel only. Is this a OpenCV version thing?
Either way I went with the sum() version, which works for multi channel mats and is fine for positive pixel values.

Comment: This does not compile in OpenCV 4.X. `countNonZero( InputArray src )` returns `int`

Comment: @martin.zaenker yep sorry my previous edit was wrong. I've updated now based on Miki's improved answer.

Answer (score 20):

The following will work also for multi-channel matrices:

```
bool isEqual = (sum(img1 != img2) == Scalar(0,0,0,0));
```

Since [sum](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#sum) accepts matrices with 1 to 4 channels, and returns a `Scalar`, where the element at [0] is the result of the sum for first channel, and so on.

Comment: what about negative values in the sum?

Comment: You sum up "boolean" values, either 0 or 255. So no problems so far

Answer (score 16):

Another way using a single function would be to use:

```
bool areIdentical = !cv::norm(img1,img2,NORM_L1);
```

Since L1 norm is calculated as `∑I|img1(I)−img2(I)|`

reference: [OpenCV norm](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga55a581f0accd8d990af775d378e7e46c)

Comment: `norm` always outputs a `double` even if the images are of integral type

Comment: @Daniel It doesn't matter in this case, we only want to know if the sum of the difference is equal to zero or not. When zero, the `not` operator will convert zero to `true` and anything else to `false` which is exactly what we want.

Answer (score 14):

This is the code I use to compare generic (not depending on dimensions or type of elements) `cv::Mat` instances:

```
bool matIsEqual(const cv::Mat Mat1, const cv::Mat Mat2)
{
  if( Mat1.dims == Mat2.dims && 
    Mat1.size == Mat2.size && 
    Mat1.elemSize() == Mat2.elemSize())
  {
    if( Mat1.isContinuous() && Mat2.isContinuous())
    {
      return 0==memcmp( Mat1.ptr(), Mat2.ptr(), Mat1.total()*Mat1.elemSize());
    }
    else
    {
      const cv::Mat* arrays[] = {&Mat1, &Mat2, 0};
      uchar* ptrs[2];
      cv::NAryMatIterator it( arrays, ptrs, 2);
      for(unsigned int p = 0; p < it.nplanes; p++, ++it)
        if( 0!=memcmp( it.ptrs[0], it.ptrs[1], it.size*Mat1.elemSize()) )
          return false;

      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

I don't understand, why `cv::Mat` does not have an operator `==` according to this implementation.

Comment: This answer should be on top. It is, to my knowledge, the fastest way to do the comparison.

Comment: Profiled solutions proposed by solosuper, Tim MB (std:equal method), this solution, and Miki and this solution much much faster.

Answer (score 7):

Use [cv::compare](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#compare) combined with [cv::countNonZero](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#countnonzero).

An SO question that might help you further [OpenCV compare two images and get different pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550458/opencv-compare-two-images-and-get-different-pixels)

Comment: I was the one editing the answer, because it was incomplete, but I must say that `cv::countNonZero` does not work for multichannel images.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by Acme and Tim, you can use `cv::compare`. This is the code I use to compare my `cv::Mat`:

```
 bool matIsEqual(const cv::Mat mat1, const cv::Mat mat2){
    // treat two empty mat as identical as well
    if (mat1.empty() && mat2.empty()) {
        return true;
    }
    // if dimensionality of two mat is not identical, these two mat is not identical
    if (mat1.cols != mat2.cols || mat1.rows != mat2.rows || mat1.dims != mat2.dims) {
        return false;
    }
    cv::Mat diff;
    cv::compare(mat1, mat2, diff, cv::CMP_NE);
    int nz = cv::countNonZero(diff);
    return nz==0;
}
```

It is important to stand out that the function [`cv::countNonZero` only works with `cv::Mat` of one channel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31241344/2436175), so if you need to compare two `cv::Mat` images, you need first to convert your `cv::Mat` in this way:

```
Mat gray1, gray2;
cvtColor(InputMat1, gray1, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cvtColor(InputMat2, gray2, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

where `InputMat1` and `InputMat2` are the `cv::Mat` you want to compare. 
After that you can call the function:

```
bool equal = matsEqual(gray1, gray2);
```

I took this code of this site: [OpenCV: compare whether two Mat is identical](http://dragonwood-blastevil.blogspot.com/2013/02/opencv-compare-whether-two-mat-is.html)

I hope this help you.

Comment: By converting the images into grayscale, you lose information, and potentially you make identical 2 color images originally different.

Comment: This works pretty well,  but uses a lot of cpu compared to Miki's answer.

Comment: @Antonio, not if you compare the color images and only convert the diff to grayscale before calling countNonZero() ?

Answer (score 3):

I use this:

```
bool areEqual(const cv::Mat& a, const cv::Mat& b) {
    cv::Mat temp;
    cv::bitwise_xor(a,b,temp); //It vectorizes well with SSE/NEON
    return !(cv::countNonZero(temp) );
}
```

If you have to do this operation many times, you can make this into a class, have `temp` as member and prevent the image to be allocated every time. Detail: Make `temp` mutable so that `areEqual` can be a `const` method.

Note though that [`cv::countNonZero` only works with `cv::Mat` of one channel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31241344/2436175). It's overkill, but in that case one could use [`cv::split`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#split) to split each channel into separate images and do `cv::countNonZero` on them.

Answer (score 3):

For multichannel images, you could use [cv::Mat::reshape](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a4eb96e3251417fa88b78e2abd6cfd7d8) to create a single channel image without any extra overhead.

An update of [Antonio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32647694/14325545) would be

```cpp
bool areEqual(const cv::Mat& a, const cv::Mat& b)
{
    cv::Mat temp;
    cv::bitwise_xor(a,b,temp);
    return !(cv::countNonZero(temp.reshape(1)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem of using `cv::countNonZero` is that this function only works for one-channel images. If you want to work with multichannel images, you have to take care of each channel individually. The first step is to split an image into channels. As Antonio explained, you can use `cv::split` function for this purpose. After splitting, you can use `cv::countNonZero` for each channel and sum the results along all channels by using iteration. `cv::Mat::channels` gives you the number of channels.

This is the code that I use to check whether two matrices are identical.

```
bool isEqual(cv::Mat firstImage, cv::Mat secondImage){
    cv::Mat dst;
    std::vector<cv::Mat>channels;
    int count = 0;
    cv::bitwise_xor(firstImage, secondImage, dst);
    cv::split(dst, channels);
    for (int ch = 0; ch<dst.channels();ch++){
        count += cv::countNonZero(channels[ch]);
    }
    return count == 0 ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
bool matIsEqual(const cv::Mat &m1, const cv::Mat &m2)
{
    if(m1.type() != m2.type())
        return false;
    if(m1.size() != m2.size())
        return false;
    return std::equal(m1.begin<uchar>(), m1.end<uchar>(), m2.begin<uchar>());
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old, well answered question, please explain how it complements *all* other answers.