# countNonZero function gives an assertion error in openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, assertion, projection-matrix

I tried to get horizontal projection using countNonZero() function as below.

```
Mat src = imread(INPUT_FILE, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
Mat binaryImage = src.clone();
cvtColor(src, src, CV_BGR2GRAY);

Mat horizontal = Mat::zeros(1,binaryImage.cols, CV_8UC1);

for (int i = 0; i<binaryImage.cols; i++)
{
    Mat roi = binaryImage(Rect(0, 0, 1, binaryImage.rows));

    horizontal.at<int>(0,i) = countNonZero(roi);
    cout << "Col no:" << i << " >>" << horizontal.at<int>(0, i);
}
```

But an error is occured in the line of calling countonZero() function. Error is as follows.

```
    OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.channels() == 1 && func != 0) in cv::countNo
    nZero, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win32-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\st
    at.cpp, line 549
```

Can somebody please point out the mistake?

Comment: binaryImage is a copy of src which is 3 channel color image. try cvtColor(src, binaryImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);

Comment: there's another error: switch horizontal.at<int>(0,i) to horizontal.at<unsigned char>(0,i) since you created 8 bit data type.

Comment: I did the changes and errors are solved. Thanks for that. But now I see that the value returned by countNonZero(roi) function are always zero. I also confirmed that binaryImage is not a completely a black image. (it has both black and white pixels everywhere)

Comment: did you change to cout << "Col no:" << i << " >>" << horizontal.at<unsigned char>(0, i);
 too?

Comment: @Mika I just printed the values of countNonZero(roi), as

for (int i = 0; i<binaryImage.cols; i++)
 {
  Mat roi = binaryImage(Rect(0, 0, 1, binaryImage.rows));

  cout << "\tCol no:" << i << "=" << countNonZero(roi);
 }

Comment: can you try to countNonZero on this sample matrix? Mat testMat = Mat::ones(1,256, CV_8UC1);

Comment: is the first column of your input matrix completely zero? in each iteration you read the same column! try Mat roi = binaryImage(Rect(i, 0, 1, binaryImage.rows));

Comment: @Mikhail Sorry for the delay.. but was expecting to focus back soon. I needed to check Miki's solution

Comment: @Micka Oh.. that was even a horrible mistake. I solved the problem using above comments. Thanks Mikhail and Micka.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Assertion `src.channels() == 1` means that image should have 1 channel, i.e. it has to be gray, not colored. You are calling `countNonZero` on `roi`, which is a subimage of `binaryImage`, which is a clone of `src`, which is originally colored.

I suppose you wanted to write `cvtColor(binaryImage, binaryImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);`. In this case it makes sense. However, I do not see you using `src` anywhere again, so perhaps you do not need this intermediate image. In case you do, do not call "binary", since "binary" in computer vision usually stands for black-or-white image, only two colors. Your image is "gray", since it has all shades of black and white.

Concerning your original task, Miki is right, you should use `cv::reduce` for it. He already gave you an example on how to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Other than above things I had to change,Mat roi = binaryImage(Rect(0, 0, 1, binaryImage.rows)); as this, Mat roi = binaryImage(Rect(i, 0, 1, binaryImage.rows)); I was just iterating the same column.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, you can compute horizontal projection using `reduce` giving as argument `CV_REDUCE_SUM`.

A minimal example:

```
Mat1b mat(4, 4, uchar(0));
mat(0,0) = uchar(1);
mat(0,1) = uchar(1);
mat(1,1) = uchar(1);

// mat is: 
//
// 1100
// 0100
// 0000
// 0000

// Horizontal projection, result would be a column matrix
Mat1i reducedHor;
cv::reduce(mat, reducedHor, 1, CV_REDUCE_SUM);

// reducedHor is:
//
// 2
// 1
// 0
// 0

// Vertical projection, result would be a row matrix
Mat1i reducedVer;
cv::reduce(mat, reducedVer, 0, CV_REDUCE_SUM);

// reducedVer is:
//
// 1200


// Summary
//
// 1100 > 2
// 0100 > 1
// 0000 > 0
// 0000 > 0
// 
// vvvv
// 1200
```

You can use this with your images like this:

```
// RGB image
Mat3b img = imread("path_to_image");

// Gray image, contains values in [0,255]
Mat1b gray;
cvtColor(img, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

// Binary image, contains only 0,1 values
// The sum of pixel values will equal the count of non-zero pixels
Mat1b binary;
threshold(gray, binary, 1, 1, THRESH_BINARY);

// Horizontal projection
Mat1i reducedHor;
cv::reduce(binary, reducedHor, 1, CV_REDUCE_SUM);

// Vertical projection
Mat1i reducedVer;
cv::reduce(binary, reducedVer, 0, CV_REDUCE_SUM);
```

Comment: Can u please elaborate your answer? What is reduce? Is it a function? If so how to use it for the purpose?

Comment: Sorry. Still this does not give any sense. At least u have not even used the black and white image to get its horizontal projection.

Comment: @SamithaChathuranga I updated my answer, hope it makes more sense to you.

Comment: This seems easier even though this is not my approach. I will check this soon and reply with the results. Thanks Miki.

Answer (score 0):

Convert Image into Gray scale and after that perform countNonZero(),
It will work

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
area = cv.countNonZero(gray)
```