# I use python3.5 and OpenCV 3.1.0,OpenCV function cv2.countNonZero(img) I got a error

Tags: python, c++, opencv, numpy

I get an error with the following code:

```
img = cv2.imread('temp.jpg')
z = cv2.countNonZero(img)
print(z)

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (cn == 1) in cv::countNonZero, file D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.1.0\modules\core\src\stat.cpp, line 1342
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hasee\Desktop\open\GuiFeaturesinOpenCV\Performance Measurement and Improvement Techniques\TestTickCount.py", line 29, in <module>
    z = cv2.countNonZero(img)
cv2.error: D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.1.0\modules\core\src\stat.cpp:1342: error: (215) cn == 1 in function cv::countNonZero
```

But, use if I numpy function it is ok:

```
z = np.count_nonzero(img)
print(z)
```

I don't understand why.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231565/countnonzero-function-gives-an-assertion-error-in-opencv ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Same problem, but C++ here:**

[countNonZero function gives an assertion error in openCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231565/countnonzero-function-gives-an-assertion-error-in-opencv)

**Solution:**

The OpenCV documentation of [`countNonZero`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#countnonzero) says:

> cv2.countNonZero(src) → retval
>
> Parameters:    src – single-channel array.

Lets have a look at the [`imread`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imread) documentation:

> imread(const String& filename, int flags=IMREAD_COLOR )
>
> Parameters:    src flags -
>
> =0 Return a grayscale image.
>
> <0 Return the loaded image as is (with alpha channel).

If you load an image with the default flag `IMREAD_COLOR`, OpenCV will dynamically detect if image (and the returned mat) is colored 3-channel or 1-channel grayscale.

To solve your problem, let OpenCV convert your loaded image to grayscale automatically:

```
img = cv2.imread('temp.jpg',cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
z = cv2.countNonZero(img)
print(z)
```

You could also convert your image after loading with [`cv2.cvtColor`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=cvtcolor#cvtcolor).

Your numpy code works fine because [`np.count_nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html) takes [`array_like`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/user/basics.creation.html#converting-python-array-like-objects-to-numpy-arrays) as input, which can be a lot of crazy stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @TengFei You are welcome. You can vote up my answer, if it was helpful.

Comment: Yes, your answer is helpful. I would like to vote, but this page prompted me: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 0):

When I loaded a color image, I could reproduce a similar error.

`countNonZero` in opencv requests the input image to be single channel. When it is color image (i.e. with 3 channels), it gives the error.