# Can copyMakeBorder() alter the source bits?

Tags: c++, opencv

Looking at the [basic example for `copyMakeBorder()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/copyMakeBorder/copyMakeBorder.html), we have the code:

```
copyMakeBorder( src, dst, top, bottom, left, right, borderType, value );
```

Are there any circumstances where the bits in `src` do not equal the bits in `dst(top, left, dst.height - top - bottom, dst.width - left - right)`, or in other words is the `src` always unmodified within `dst`?

I ask because I've inherited some code that adds a border with `cv::BORDER_REFLECT + cv::BORDER_ISOLATED` but then extracts the `src` from inside the borders, so I'm suspicious that this is all unnecessary work.

Furthermore, I've used [the code here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11905590/1270789) to convince myself that for the current code the `src` and the centre of the `dst` are equal, but I'd still like confirmation that my assumptions are correct.

Comment: check the size of the image using `img.shape` and compare

Comment: @JeruLuke I can empirically check that way, but I'd like to know for sure. The documentation is not clear on exactly what happens.

Comment: No, the values in the original image are never altered. You can check [the soruce code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/copy.cpp#L1190) to convince yourself