# Using a function as a convolution kernel

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Hello fellow programmers,

I am currently doing this years [advent of code](https://adventofcode.com/2021).
On [day 9](https://adventofcode.com/2021/day/9) I need to find out wether a pixel in an image has the smallest value of the adjacent pixels.

I first solved this very intuitively and crudely, but now after looking at it for a while was wondering if there was a way to define a convolution kernel for opencv's  [`filter2D`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filter2d)-function or another appropriate library I could try where I can define the kernel as a function, such that I can not only perform linear transformations, but also others.

In this specific example I was thinking about a kernel, that can tell if the middle pixel has the lowest value. Maybe there even is a way to do this using linear transformations, however i am not able to find it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: erode/dilate, compare, done. erode/dilate are *not* linear, which is why they can solve this. nothing linear can solve this.

Comment: would you believe i went through the exact same reasoning for yesterday's AOC problem.  ended up hacking it "crude" way

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks a lot! Did not know about those operations. Always learning :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution myself simply using [`scipy.ndimage.generic_filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.generic_filter.html#scipy.ndimage.generic_filter)

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import generic_filter

# First define the footprint of the filter you are going to use:
footprint = np.array([[False, True, False],
                     [True, True, True],
                     [False, True, False]])

# Then define the filter you want to use:
def lowpoint_kernel(a):
    return 0 if a[2] < a[0] and a[2] < a[1] and a[2] < a[3] and a[2] < a[4] else 10

# Get your input here
image = ...

# Pad your image
image = np.pad(image, 1, constant_values=10)

lowpoints = generic_filter(image, lowpoint_kernel, footprint=footprint)
lowpoint_indices = lowpoints == 0
```

This might very well be a very complicated solution, but maybe someone can find this useful.
See my full solution [here](https://github.com/LennartEing/aoc21/blob/main/day9/__init__.py).

Answer (score 0):

That is a good idea in python to use scipy general filter.
But as far as I know OpenCV does not provide such a way (custom function handle as a filter). So, if you want to use OpenCV functions to do so, you can first apply an **erosion morphology operation** ([cv::erode](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gaeb1e0c1033e3f6b891a25d0511362aeb))  (with your desire windows size and binary mask) to obtain the minimum at each pixel neighborhood and then compare the resulted image with the original one using [cv::compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905093/how-to-check-whether-two-matrices-are-identical-in-opencv) method or the like.
To exclude center pixel in minimum (erosion), you can pass a **customized binary kernel** to cv::erode, where the center pixel is zero in the generated kernel.
All in all, you should do something like this:

1. cv::Mat kernel = cv::Mat::ones(3,3,CV_8UC1);
   kernel.at(1, 1)=0;
2. cv::erode(src, dst_min, kernel);
3. cv::compare(src, dst_min, dst, cv::CMP_EQ);

Having said that the only limitation of this method is that the minimum operation is computed over non-zero neighbors in the cv::erode function. If this is not your desire effect, you can add a bias to the src, an then subtract it!

Last but not least, if you are working with cpu (and not gpu), I do recommend [**cv::ParallelLoopBody**](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/dff/tutorial_how_to_use_OpenCV_parallel_for_.html) to implement all of the procedure in parallel with just one call (memory access).