# Swift: How do I test two OpenCV Mat for equality in swift

Tags: swift, opencv

How do I apply this answer [how to check whether two matrices are identical in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905093/how-to-check-whether-two-matrices-are-identical-in-opencv) to swift?

```
 let output = Mat(rows: input.rows(), cols: input.cols(), type: CvType.CV_8UC1)
 let test = Mat(rows: input.rows(), cols: input.cols(), type: CvType.CV_8UC1)
  ... fill test and output...
    if(!test.isSameMat(output)) {
        for x in 0 ..< output.rows() {
            for y in 0 ..< output.cols() {
                let value = output.get(row: x, col: y)
                let t = test.get(row: x, col: y)
                if t != value {
                    print("first mismatch row \(x) cols \(y)") <- this does not
                }
            }
        }
        assert(test.isSameMat(output)) <- this does trip for both isSameMat and isEqual
    }
```

Comment: it's a objc interface in opencv lib derived from NSObject, are you saying isEqual is implemented properly?

Comment: It is OpenCV Mat. I've updated the question with output and test declarations. These are single channel matrices whatever that means if that's makes comparison life any easier.

Comment: output.isEqual(test) returns false also. go figure how that logic works.

Comment: Which OpenCV library is this? (Link the home page or docs please). Swift can’t interoperate directly with C++ (yet, it’s WIP), so I presume this is some variant of OpenCV that’s targeted towards Swift (or maybe just C?)

Comment: Here https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases

Comment: Hold up, I don't follow. That's just the "regular ol'" OpenCV, which as far as I understood, is a library that uses C++ heavily. Swift can't call C++ APIs, unless they're bridged through Objective-C++ (which I highly doubt is the case here) or they're "dumbed down" (that seems plausible). So how does this work?

Comment: It's a "dumbed down" crude API. So the question is how do I compare Mat rices in swift: C++ answer I linked might be a starting point or of no help at all. I dunno yet.

Comment: So it comes down to the particulars of OpenCV, and whether or not they expose C bindings for those C++ APIs like `cv::countNonZero`. If not, you'll have to write your own C or Objective-C++ glue code.